# WAI-ARIA Roles for Carousels (a.k.a. sliders, slideshows, galleries)

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

What [WAI-ARIA roles](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/roles) should be used for carousels, like the one below?

[image: USA.gov carousel example]

**Notes:**

- I'm familiar with the [slider](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/roles#slider) role, but this refers to a different type of widget.
- The example is from [USA.gov](http://www.usa.gov/) and the only aria role I see in use that's related to the carousel is `aria-live` on the individual slides.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as you correctly say, `role=slider` is not right for a carousel. The one that you should use is `role=listbox`

quoting from MDN (see link below):

> The listbox role is used to identify an element that creates a list from which a user may select one or more items which are static and, unlike HTML  elements, may contain images.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_listbox_role for additional information on other ARIA roles you should use, such as `role=option` for each entry in the listbox.

You could also have a look at this YUI plugin (YUI 2 is deprecated but the documentation is still valid for the purpose of your question)
http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/examples/carousel/carousel-ariaplugin.html

that adds aria roles to an existing carousel via javascript. I'm not suggesting to use it, but you can certainly infer what it does and replicate it in your markup as needed.

Comment: The intent of a listbox is to be used as a form element, which is why it is a subclass of `select`. More appropriate roles would be `tablist` (if the links to each item in the carousel are provided and shown as active), or `marquee`.

Answer (score 9):

I have seen many examples using `role="listbox"`, but this feels incorrect to me.  A listbox is a form control, wanting to get a selection from a user.  If the purpose of your carousel is to have a user select an option, then use `listbox`, but most people do not use carousel components in this manner.  A better role would be a `tablist`.  Tablists are used to represent data (as opposed to capturing an option). Carousel represent data.  The links to display a certain image would have the role of `tab` and each image with it's corresponding data such as its caption would get a role of `tabpanel`.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-wai-aria-practices-20100916/#tabpanel

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of an accessible carousel using jQuery UI: 
http://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_carousel

The control bar is a list of images, marked up with `<ul role="listbox">`. Each `<li>` has `role="option"`, `tabindex="-1"`, and `aria-selected="false"`.

The two arrows are `<button>` elements with `title="previous"` and `title="next"`, and when a button is pressed the previous or next list item is selected, in which case that list item's attributes change to `aria-selected="true"` and `tabindex="0"`. The latter means the user can tab directly to the current selected image, which of course has suitable alt text.

Another option not included in this example might be to add `role="alert"` to the viewer div, so when the content of that div changes the new alt text is automatically read. That way users don't have to press <kbd>tab</kbd> to see what the image is, then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to go back to the button.

Answer (score 6):

From the [**official** W3 tutorials](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/structure/#using-wai-aria-roles-and-labels):

> To group the carousel in a way that is perceivable for assistive technologies, the `role` attribute with a value of `region` can be used. To identify the region, the `aria-label` attribute can be used, as show in the example below:
>
> ```
> <div class="carousel" role="region" aria-label="Recent news">
>     …
> </div>
> ```

So you should use **`role="region"`**

Comment: Note that `region` is a landmark role and not a widget role. This means you are labeling the group and not the widget itself. I think this is at odds with the intent of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Now that other answers already can't agree on role "listbox", "region" or "marquee", another one pops up: role "group", in combination with role description "carousel".

From the, very official, [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#basic-carousel-elements) (emphasis mine):

> - A carousel container element [...] has either
>   role region or **role group**. The most appropriate role for the
>   carousel container depends on the information architecture of the
>   page. [...]
> - The carousel container has the **aria-roledescription property set to carousel**.

A11y is hard.

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr:

[`role="marquee"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#marquee)

---

A carousel is **not** a [listbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#listbox).

From the listbox description

> A widget that allows the user to select one or more items from a list of choices.

The listbox role is a subclass of [select](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#select). While I'm sure there are exceptions, carousels are generally not used as form elements where users "select one or more items", and should not use a role that would otherwise treat them as such.

A better role for a carousel is [tablist](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#tablist) so long as bullets or numbering for the carousel slides are provided and toggle depending on which one is active:

> A list of tab elements, which are references to tabpanel elements.

An all around-better role for carousels is [marquee](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#marquee), as there is no dependency on showing "tabs" as bullets or numbers to access different slides:

> A type of live region where non-essential information changes frequently.

Comment: `role="marquee"` does _not_ seem like an generally appropriate role. The reason is, that in reality many sliders/carousels “hide” a lot of _essential_ information and are not necessarily autoplaying. That said, [carousels are a proven ineffective user-experience on their own](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective).

Comment: @VolkerE., I also explicitly called out `role="tablist"` depending on your use case. [I agree that carousels are crap](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/), but that's not relevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: You're starting with tl;dr [use] `role=marquee`, which is not an “all around-better role” or a generally recommendable answer for carousels – if at all, then only for very specific carousel sub-types. Therefore it's misleading and might result in worsened experience for screenreader users.

Comment: @VolkerE., from [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#marquee) "marquee (role) A type of live region where non-essential information changes frequently.". I consider that to be an apt description of just about every carousel I've ever seen or used.

Comment: As I've stated in my first comment, “in reality many sliders/carousels “hide” a lot of essential information”. That could be a definition difference between you and me or simply a weakness in the standard definition. Given my experience on both sides, as consumer and developer of carousels, I came across various carousels with hidden elements on first sight featuring said essential information. (As developer I have clearly argued against their usage)

Answer (score 0):

This reference may not have been around when the original question was posted but it is a very official source with clear instructions. A11y is a learning process.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/carousel/carousel-1-prev-next

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).